# How to generate with rowspan in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Maybe someone could help me with one question, I'm actually trying to generate A structure usin Angular Js like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Modo de transporte</th>
    <th>Estado del proyecto</th>
    <th>Proyecto</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="6">Carretero</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Estructuración</td>
    <td>Proyecto 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Proyecto 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Contratación</td>
    <td>Proyecto 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Proyecto 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Gestion contractual</td>
    <td>Proyecto 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Proyecto 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4">Aeropuertos</td>
    <td>Estructuracion</td>
    <td>Proyecto 7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Contratación</td>
    <td>Proyecto 8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Proyecto 9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Gestion contractual</td>
    <td>Proyecto 10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but using this .js code

```
$scope.regional = {
distribution: {
  "Arauca": {
     modes: {
       "Aeropuertos": {
         status: {
           "Estructuracion": ["Nodo 1", "Nodo 2", "Nodo 3"],
           "Contratacion": ["Nodo 1", "Nodo 2"],
         },
         count: function(){
           var c = 0;
           for(var k in this.status){
             c += this.status[k].length;
           }
           return c;
         }
       }
     },
     count: function(){
       var c = 0;
       for(var m in this.modes){
         c += this.modes[m].count();
       }
       return c;
     }
   }
}
};
```

```
<table ng-repeat="(dpto, intodpto) in regional.distribution">
  <caption>{{dpto}}</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Modo de transporte</th>
    <th>Estado del proyecto</th>
    <th>Proyecto</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="(mode, intomode) in intodpto.modes">
    <td rowspan="{{intomode.count()}}">{{mode}}</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr ng-repeat-start="(status, intostatus) in intomode.status">
    <td rowspan={{intostatus.length}}>{{status}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="proj in intostatus">
    <td>{{proj}}</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
</table>`
```

How can I combine that, I'm using ng-repeat-start to do the js code, thanks a lot for any suggestions

Comment: I think I missed something. What is the problem here?

Comment: Hello , I am trying to create a similar to the first block of code table.

I have this so far [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/IaASzT8l8JsG6KVPmMQw?p=preview)